# How to select a dict key that is inside a list of dicts holding list and more dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list called:

```
all_players = []
```

A method called `get_teams()` which takes an URL and returns a list that holds dicts of a team name and URL of the team, and example of the output will be

```
teams = get_teams(url)
```

will return

```
[{'name': 'Dallas', 'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021%E2%80%9322_Dallas_Mavericks_season'}, {'name': 'Phoenix', 'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021%E2%80%9322_Phoenix_Suns_season'},...
```

A method called `get_player(url)`, that takes the URL of the team and returns a list holding dicts of names and URL of the player, a return will look like this:

```
[{'name': 'Jaylen Brown', 'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaylen_Brown'}, {'name': 'Malik Fitts', 'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malik_Fitts'}, {'name': 'Sam Hauser', 'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Hauser'},...
```

So, what I have done so far is this:

```
for x in teams:
    all_players.append({x['name']: get_players(x['url'])})
```

printing out with this for loop:

```
for c in all_players:
     print(c)
     print()
```

will return this

```
{'Dallas': [{'name': 'Dāvis Bertāns', 'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%81vis_Bert%C4%81ns'}, {'name': 'Sterling Brown (basketball)', 'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterling_Brown_(basketball)'},...
```

in the format

```
[{"team name": [{ "name": "player name", "url": "https://player_url"},...
```

I will try to explain what I want to do as clear as I can :)

What I want to do is, to take the url that is inside `all_players` ( this on: "url": "https://player_url") which means, go inside the list, inside the dict , get the value of the team name, this value is a list, so I want to go inside the list and take the url value. With this url value I want to use a method called `get_player_stats(url, teamname)` which will add 3 more keys to the dict which is inside the team name value list.

I have absolutely no idea how to take the url and then add new values to that dict which are returned by the method.

Any hint or idea would be highly appreciated.

just an example on how the final dict inside the all_players would look like:

```
{     "team name": [{ "name": "player name", "url": "https://player_url", "newkey1":1, "newkey2: 2, "newkey3":3 },...]}
```

What I have tried:

```
for x in all_players:
    for team, players in x.items():
        for n in players:   
            print(n['url]')
```

Using 3 loops I can get into the url, and i can use `get_player_stats()`, but I'm not sure how to append this to `all_players` the way I described over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close to the answer. So in this step of your program your `all_players` list should look something like this:

```py
all_players = {
    "Dallas": [
        {
            "name": "Dāvis Bertāns",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%81vis_Bert%C4%81ns",
        },
        {
            "name": "Sterling Brown (basketball)",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterling_Brown_(basketball)",
        },
    ],
    "Team2": [
        {
            "name": "sample1",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/sample1",
        },
        {
            "name": "sample2",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/sample2",
        },
    ],
}
```

You need to first get the player's url, then call `get_player_stats` function. Here is the code:

```py
from pprint import pprint

def get_player_stats(url, team_name):
    # get information based on `url`.
    team_name["newkey1"] = 1
    team_name["newkey2"] = 2


for team, players in all_players.items():
    for player in players:
        player_url = player["url"]
        get_player_stats(player_url, player)

pprint(all_players, sort_dicts=False)
```

Look at the loop, when you get the URL, you also have access to the player dictionary which is `player`. So pass it to the `get_player_stats` and it can mutate it! `team_name` is your `player` dictionary.

output:

```
{'Dallas': [{'name': 'Dāvis Bertāns',
             'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%81vis_Bert%C4%81ns',
             'newkey1': 1,
             'newkey2': 2},
            {'name': 'Sterling Brown (basketball)',
             'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterling_Brown_(basketball)',
             'newkey1': 1,
             'newkey2': 2}],
 'Team2': [{'name': 'sample1',
            'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/sample1',
            'newkey1': 1,
            'newkey2': 2},
           {'name': 'sample2',
            'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/sample2',
            'newkey1': 1,
            'newkey2': 2}]}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, you have written get_player_stats(player_url, player), in my case i have to pass team instead of player, so get_player_stats(player_url, team). get_player_stats will return a dict, i see that I have not specified that in the question correctly. it returns {'newkey1' : 1 , 'newkey2' : 2}. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @ili I used the signature you provided in your question. `players` was a list of `player` dictionaries, so `player` is a dictionary. If you want to return a dictionary from `get_player_stats`, that's also possible just `.update()` your `player` dictionary afterward.